# Can oninput substitute onchange and onpaste?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on a regex to check for non-whitelisted characters. I would like to use the oninput event in my HTML to trigger the regex check.  Will this approach yield the same results as if I tried to use onchange or onpaste together somehow?

Thanks!

Javascript:

`function checkInput(txtfieldId)
    var validChars = /^[0-9a-z\s-.#\,()]+$/i;
      {

       if(txtfieldId.value.match(validChars))
         {
          return true;
         }
       else
         {
          alert("Invalid special character entered");
          return false;
         }
      }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `keypress` event and check if the input is valid and prevent the default action with `event.preventDefault()` if it is not.

```html
<input type="text" id="input" ondrop="return false" ondragover="return false"/>
<script>
var validChars = /^[0-9a-z\s-.#\,()]+$/i;
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("paste", function(e){
var clipboardData, pastedData;
// Get pasted data via clipboard API
clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
var inputOk = checkInput(pastedData);
if(!inputOk){
  e.preventDefault();
}
});
document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  var inputOk = checkInput(e.key);
  if(!inputOk){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
function checkInput(value)
      {

       if(value.match(validChars))
         {
          return true;
         }
       else
         {
          alert("Invalid special character entered");
          return false;
         }
      }
</script>
```

If you have multiple `textarea`s with a certain class that you want to prevent entering special characters in, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.class')` to get all of the elements with that class. You can then use a `for` loop or `for Each` to add an event listener to all of the elements.

```html
<textarea class='txt'></textarea><p/>
<textarea class='txt'></textarea><p/>
<textarea class='txt'></textarea><p/>
<textarea class='txt'></textarea><p/>
<textarea class='txt'></textarea><p/>
<textarea class='txt'></textarea><p/>
<script>
var validChars = /^[0-9a-z\s-.#\,()]+$/i;
document.querySelectorAll('.txt').forEach(function(i){
   i.addEventListener("paste", function(e){
var clipboardData, pastedData;
// Get pasted data via clipboard API
clipboardData = e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
pastedData = clipboardData.getData('Text');
var inputOk = checkInput(pastedData);
if(!inputOk){
  e.preventDefault();
}
});
 i.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  var inputOk = checkInput(e.key);
  if(!inputOk){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
});
function checkInput(value)
      {

       if(value.match(validChars))
         {
          return true;
         }
       else
         {
          alert("Invalid special character entered");
          return false;
         }
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works great for keyed in text.  However, I haven't been able to get it to work with text that is pasted into the field. Changing "keypress" to "paste" doesn't seem to work. I'd like to make this work for both types of events. Sorry for my noobitity!

Comment: @Jupitar I have prevented other forms of input.

Comment: So sorry, I should clarify.  I need the function to also throw the alert when someone attempts to paste in non-whitelisted character.  I still need to keep the ability to paste in text. I appreciate your time!

Comment: @Jupitar I have added paste handling.

Comment: Ah, I see that the event listeners are separated.  Now I know that they must be separated and can't be combined.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jupitar No problem.

Comment: So I found out I needed to use something like getElementsByClassName instead of getElementById.  However, this change causes "e.preventDefault();" to fail. This keeps the invalid character in the text area.  Is there something I can change to fix this?

Comment: @Jupitar If there is only one element with that class name, you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].addEventListener()`. If there are multiple elements you need to add an event listener to, you can use `document.querySelectorAll('.classname').forEach(i=>i.addEventListener())`.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple elements, six text fields exactly. I've tried adding the querySelectorAll line you provided in a few areas, but it either causes the function to fail completely or I have the same result that I commented today.  You you point me in the right direction again?

Comment: @Jupitar No problem.

Comment: Great... looks like forEach() is not supported by IE... Is there a way to make this work in IE without having to change too much?

Comment: @Jupitar No problem.

Comment: So I had to change /^[0-9a-z\s-.#\,()]+$/i; to /^[ 0-9a-z\s.#,-]*$/i; but now IE accepts the non-whitelisted characters via the number pad.  Is there a way to fix it? Sorry to pester!

Comment: Specifically, it allows /,*, and + via numpad.  It still blocks them via the the regular number row. IE only.